# Bandwith monitoring in a network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, xen, bandwidth

We have a Internal lab system with some four physical machines.

In four physical machines we have three machines with XenServer installed which is have XenVms and One Machine with Virtual box installed and virtualmachines in it.

I need to do monitor the bandwidth Usage in the VM's in it.

Consider Internal Lab Systems is having IP in the following range 172.17.3.0/24.

So need to check the bandwidth consumption in and every Machines from one machine.

I am planning to create a python script for the same.

Some one suggest the modules or idea how we can achieve this.

Note: VM may be of ubuntu or Centos Flavor

Checked SNMP , Zabbix etc its not seems to be the best option for me.

Comment: Maybe MRTG can do the work for you: http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Comment: ganglia has also nice graphs and can be installed from default repositories  and in case of CentOS from epel.